# call models function in the view in joomla?

Tags: model-view-controller, view, model, joomla

I have the following function in my model

```
function abc_list(){

        global $mainframe;

        $db      =& JFactory::getDBO();

            echo '<ul><li class="all"><a class="ajax_all" href="#"/> alle </a></li>';     

                foreach(range('a','z') as $i):{

                                    $query = "SELECT * FROM #__glossary WHERE tterm  LIKE '$i%' AND published = 1";

                                    $db->setQuery( $query );

                                    $css .= '<li class = "searchAbc">';

                                    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();

                                    if ($rows){

                                    $css .= '<a class="button" href="\''.$i.'" value="'.$i.'"/>'.$i.'</a>';}

                                    else {

                                    $css .= $i;    

                                    }

                                    $css .='</li> </ul>';


                                    }
                        endforeach; 

                                    return $css;

         }
```

and I would like out up in my view, but because of some reasons doesn't really works.

I was trying this in the following way

```
$abc          = $this->get('abc_list');
```

in this case the $abc variable seems to be empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this :

```
$model      = $this->getModel();
$abc = $model->abc_list();
var_dump($abc);
```

Comment: seems to be okay just at the end of my outputted string I have a null message as well, but maybe this one is an xdebug message

Answer (score 1):

To Access a different model, use:

```
$model = JModel::getInstance('MODEL_NAME', 'COMPONENTNAME');        
$items= $model->getItems();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should have get prefixed to your funstion name than only that will work. ex. getabc_list.
better you name it like this *getAbcList* and call *$this->get('AbcList')*